# Simplfying Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi im just learning Jquery atm, and I'm wondering what is the best method for simplifying the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.hover').hide();

$( '.state' ).hover(function() {
    $('.divtop .state').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 300),
    $('.divtop .hover').show(),
    $('.divtop .hover').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
    },

    function() {
    $('.divtop .hover').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 600,'',function(){$(this).hide()});
    $('.divtop .state').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 500);

    });

$( '.divmiddle .state' ).hover(function() {
    $('.divmiddle .state').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 300),
    $('.divmiddle .hover').show(),
    $('.divmiddle .hover').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
    }, function() {

    $('.divmiddle .hover').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 600,'',function(){$(this).hide()});
    $('.divmiddle .state').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 500);

    });

$( '.divbottom .state' ).hover(function() {
    $('.divbottom .state').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 300),
    $('.divbottom .hover').show(),
    $('.divbottom .hover').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
    }, function() {

    $('.divbottom .hover').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 600,'',function(){$(this).hide()});
    $('.divbottom .state').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 500);

    });
});
```

The html looks like so:

```
<section class="left">
            <div class="divtop">
                <img src="img/layout/blue.png" class="state" alt="blue" />
                <img src="img/layout/bluehover.png" class="hover" alt="bluehover" />
            </div><!-- close class divtop -->
            <div class="divmiddle">
                <img src="img/layout/red.png" class="state" alt="red" />
                <img src="img/layout/redhover.png" class="hover" alt="redhover" />
            </div><!-- close class divmiddle -->
            <div class="divbottom">
                <img src="img/layout/pink.png" class="state" alt="pink" />
                <img src="img/layout/pinkhover.png" class="hover" alt="pinkhover" />
            </div><!-- close class divbottom -->

        </section><!-- close left section -->
```

The images in css are positioned absolute so they lie on top of each other.

Comment: if it works, don't worry about it. if it were slow then you could do some optimizing, but if you're just starting out with jQuery, don't worry about optimizing ever last bit of code, just write it so that you can understand it in case you have to change it later.

Comment: Should be migrated to Code Review SE site.

Comment: @MrOBrian I couldn't disagree more.  Learning proper code organization techniques is critical to "changing it later" and is also a language agnostic skill that will make you a better all around programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do...

```
$(function() {
  $('.hover').hide();
  $('.state' ).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 300);
    $(this).siblings('.hover').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
  }, function() {
    $(this).siblings('.hover').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 600, function() { $(this).hide(); });
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1}, 500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Code duplication is not a JS or jQuery issue, just a general programming thing. So try refactor duplicated code into reusable functions or methods.  How about we make a function to bind the hover handling for us, since we do it the same way 3 times.

Also, don't overuse the `$('#selector')` in jQuery. Why search for the same element multiple times when you can sve the result an use the element as a variable more directly.

So I'd do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v8srd/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Hide all the elements that should be shown on hover
  $('.hover').hide();

  // One function to setup all hovers
  var setupHover = function(position) {

    // Find the parent element that contains the state and the hover,
    // then find the state/hover elements within the parent
    var parent = $('.div' + position),
        state = parent.find('.state'),
        hover = parent.find('.hover');

    // Apply the hover to the above elements
    state.hover(function() {
      state.stop().animate({opacity:0}, 300),
      hover.show().stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
    }, function() {
      hover.stop().animate({opacity:0}, 600,'',function(){$(this).hide()});
      state.stop().animate({opacity:1}, 500);
    });
  };

  // Bind the hover handling to each position
  setupHover('top');
  setupHover('middle');
  setupHover('bottom');
});​
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments! they definitely saved me time trying to figure out what each code was doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way could be as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.hover').hide();

   $( 'section.left > div' ).hover(function() {
      $(this).children('.state').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 300),
      $(this).children('.hover').show(),
      $(this).children('.hover').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
   },
   function() {
      $(this).children('.hover').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 600,'',function(){$(this).hide()});
      $(this).children('.state').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 500);
   });
});
```

that should simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the common part of the code in a function, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function hover(sel, sel2){
    $(sel).hover(function() {
      $(sel2 + ' .state').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 300),
      $(sel2 + ' .hover').show().stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
    }, function() {
      $(sel2 + ' .hover').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 600,'',function(){$(this).hide()});
      $(sel2 + ' .state').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 500);
    });
  }

  $('.hover').hide();
  hover('.state', '.divtop');
  hover('.divmiddle .state', '.divmiddle');
  hover('.divbottom .state', '.divbottom');
});
```